# Laravel - delete specific post from logged in user

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a delete button on a post from a user that is logged in. The logged in user can see other peoples posts, and only delete his own. I already managed that the delete button only appears on his own posts. I think the problem is in the route in the view..

Controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $post->delete;

    return view('/home', [
        'posts' => $post
    ]);
}
```

view:

```
   @if ($post->checkUser(Auth::user()))
        <form action="{{ route('posts.destroy, $post') }}" method="POST">
              <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                      {{ csrf_field() }}
                      {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

                        <button>Delete</button>
         </form>
  @endif
```

Route:

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
```

Comment: So what is the actual error?

Comment: @joe Route [posts.destroy, $post] not defined. ..

Answer (score 6):

Change `$post->delete;` to `$post->delete()`; because delete() method is a function. And if you use resource you should send request with delete method for call destroy method. but you can not do it from form because for support only post and get, another solution you can use hidden input and send with post method, `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">`

Comment: I'm updated answer. You can check also this article https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-updatedelete-using-forms-and-restful-controllers?page=1

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify post_id and user_id both.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $user_id = Auth::user();
    $post = Post::where('post_id', $id)->where('user_id',$user_id)-get();
    $post->delete();

    // do your rest of code
}
```

Change post_id and user_id name according to your table field name.

Comment: thank you but i have a problem in my route or view @Rahul

Comment: @Mette try this: <form action="/posts" method="delete"> and make sure your form is submit or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should edit the route in your view to look like this,

`route('posts.destroy, ['id' => $post->id]')`, if that doesn't work check your named route again by doing `php artisan route:list`, and also try to post the full error for better understanding.

Comment: This is the error..ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 304: Route [posts.destroy, ["id" => $post->id]] not defined. in the view

Comment: Check your routes in `php artisan route:list`, and see if posts.destroy is mapped correctly and that it expects a wildcard, ex `/posts/{post}`, also try running `php artisan route:clear` to clear the cache